# Is it possible to pass a class as an argument of a function in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

Here is some pseudo code of what I would like to do:

```
void thing (storedClassArg){
    virtualClass<x,y> in1 = new storedClassArg<x,y>;
    virtualClass<x,z> in2 = new storedClassArg<x,z>;
}
 
main:
storedClass;
if( inputThingy)
    storedClass = type1;
else
    storedClass = type2;
thing(storedClass);
```

Comment: This is not possible in C++ yet. Various proposals on incorporating reflection into C++ are being considered for C++17.

Comment: @BrianBi Wow, you actually understood the question?

Comment: Actually right now only *compile-time* reflection is being considered. They said they were looking at compile-time reflection first because it would likely determine what kind of runtime reflection facilities should exist. So don't expect it until C++23...

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't know exactly what OP wants to do but it definitely seems like reflection...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some fairy language, not [tag:c++] ...

Comment: Doesn't look like reflection to me.  Looks broken.  `main` treats `storedClass` like a variant or base class pointer in a factory, then if I *had* to guess I'd hazard that `thing` wants to do a `.clone()` to create a local variable of whatever type the function argument turned out to be.

Comment: This can *sort of* be done using RTTI.  For example, MFC has a `RuntimeClass` class that you can pass around and actually use to generate an instance of a class, but the requirements to accomplish it are not trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

You can't pass a class as an argument to a function. You can only pass a *value*. A value refers to either an object or a function.

You *can* pass a class as an argument to a template. However, template arguments must be determined at compile-time, not run-time.

C++ provides run-time polymorphism only through inheritance. If you want to create an object whose type will not be known until run-time, what you can do is to make all possible types you might want to create derived classes of a common base.

Even still, you can't use the type *itself*, that you want to create, as an argument to a function. You'll have to pass in some other value and then branch on that to determine which type you want to create at run-time.

Comment: "C++ provides run-time polymorphism only through inheritance." - with dedicated language support - true, but you've also got the option to coordinate it manually through a mix of more general language features (`union`, `reinterpret_cast`, placement `new` etc., type-lists), e.g. `boost::variant` and `boost::any`.